# Setting up dns server on an isolated lan

Tags: windows-7, dns, lan

I have a LAN with 2 laptops, 1 router, 2 NAS and a printer.
I want to have a dns service but i do not want to have a pc permanently connected for that service.
As i can define a preferred and an alternative dns server, can i use the 2 laptops for that? If none of the laptops are connected i do not need the dns service, and if at least one of them is connected it can be the dns server?
If so, what should i use as dns server without affecting the performance of those laptops?
Note: both of them run Win 7

Thank you

Rui

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should work, but I would argue against it for a few reasons, not the least of which being that you could probably run DNS on one of the NASs, and achieve the same result as having a dedicated server box.

1) if you lan is in fact isolated, and you only have two hosts, why do you need DNS at all? a hosts file would be just as manageable, especially if you are hosting your zone on both nodes.

2) you will have to duplicate any zone changes on both laptops, or manually perform zone transfers, since you can't do zone transfers on a schedule.

3) Performance for clients will be reduced, because each DNS query may or may not resolve against the active server, and the application requesting the lookup will have to wait two seconds before it decides the request has failed.

4) the MS DNS server is not available on Windows7, so you will have to find a 3rd party service, install and configure it.